# construction of a data model on cassandra / CQL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have a vehicle tracking table that contains the following fields: `vehicle_id, id tracking, time_tracking, longitude, latitude`. How to build the table so that I can have the latest tracking of all vehicles according to time_tracking. How to build the table also to have the last tracking of a vehicle also according to time_tracking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No cultural disrespect intended here, but this site's policy is to post questions in English. See here for an explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Okey , like now !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the columns specified you can try the below schema.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_details (time_tracking timestamp,
                                      vehicle_id int,
                                      id int,
                                      latitude varchar,
                                      longitude varchar,
                                      PRIMARY KEY ((time_tracking), vehicle_id)
                                      )WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_tracking DESC);
```

Since you are storing in a CLUSTERING ORDER of DESC, it will always be very easy to get the latest records, you need to add 'LIMIT' to your query,

`Ex: select * from vehicle_details where time_tracking=20200101 limit 10;`

You can run a select query based on `time_tracking` and can add `vehicle_id` to get the details of vehicle for a particular timestamp.

`Ex: select * from vehicle_details where time_tracking=20200101 and vehicle_id = 122 limit 10;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply,it's helpful but I don't know if you have any idea  about getting the last tracking of all vehicles , for example : vehicle 100 : last tracking ,vehicle 101 :last tracking , vehicle 102 : last tracking.
without specifying the id of vehicle.